# Package which is a dependency of my library isn't installed (@angular/material/core not found)

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, yarnpkg, nomachine-nx

I got a angular custom library `@foo/bar`, which has these dependencies:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/material": "11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@custom-library-1": "^0.0.5",
    "@custom-library-2": "^0.0.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  },
```

When I install this library using `yarn add @foo/bar` in a clean project (with only an empty package.json), and I navigate to `node_modules/@angular`, I see the folder `@angular/material/core`.

Now, I'm removing my `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`, and I'm adding the following dependencies to this project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/common": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/core": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/forms": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/router": "9.1.11",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "9.4.4",
    "@custom-library-1": "^0.0.1",
    "@custom-library-1": "^0.0.5",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "6.5.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1",
    "@foo/bar": "0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.901.9",
    "@angular/cli": "9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.1.11",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^4.2.0",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "9.4.4",
    "@nrwl/jest": "9.4.4",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "9.4.4",
    "@types/jest": "25.1.4",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.585.0",
    "codelyzer": "~5.0.1",
    "cypress": "3.8.2",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "express-serve-static-core": "^0.1.1",
    "jest": "25.2.4",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.1.3",
    "prettier": "2.0.4",
    "readdir-enhanced": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-jest": "25.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "6.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.8.3"
  }
```

Now when I try to build the project, I'm gettin this error:

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "@foo/bar" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/material/core
```

Also, when I navigate to `node_modules/@angular`, I notice the entire `@angular/material` is gone. Anyone knows why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `yarn install` command ran through without any issues, otherwise it might be that your installation failed and lead to an incomplete `node_modules` folder.

I created a project with this setup and don't encounter this issue.
This is probably an issue with your tools (yarn, angular cli).

**My setup:**

Angular CLI 11.0.2
Node: 12.18.2
Yarn 1.22.4

**On a side note:**

You are creating mix of different Angular versions, which probably doesn't help either, e.g.:

```
"@angular/material": "11.0.1",
"@angular/common": "^10.0.14",
"@angular/cli": "9.1.9"
```

Comment: Upgrading angular to the same latest versions did solve another issue, but unfortunately not the one the question is about